# Arduino Ethernet W5100 can not DHCP correctly

Tags: arduino

a few days ago I use ESP8266+w5100 try to run a TCP/IP program by Arduino IDE, but I fail, Arduino IDE said that it can't found W5100,every process I was following other who was success but still fail. it's noting.

This time I use Arduino + Arduino ethernet shield try to run a TCP program .This time Arduino IDE can found the ethernet shield. But it can't DCHP. Every time I connect shield to my laptop it shows the IP is 169.254 network segment. I know that it was a segment with problems .So I change a network cable but still failed.

Now I just want to run a common program successfully. For example, Arduino Procedures on the official website named [DHCP Address Printer](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LibraryExamples/DhcpAddressPrinter). Does someone know what's wrong on it？

Comment: does it work with static IP address? what is the output of the WebClient example? it has enhanced diagnostics.

Comment: serial shows normal operation. If Arduino set IP 192.168.1.177 it can show in serial info, but PC show the DCHP IP is 169.254.xxx.xxx. So I have to change static IP in PC. After changing I still can't ping Arduino.

Comment: When I use DCHP for IP assignment, it also shows 169.254.xxx. XXX network segment. other people said 169.254 network segment can't not normal work.